# SVN Control Commit Access

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can I control who can commit the projects?
I Need to introduce a rule that only one person can commit one specific project at the same time. 
And the person who want to make changes he only can when he Update the project, that was previously committed.

As in the following example:

1. - User 1 working on the project
2. - User 2 attempts to commit, but access is denied because User 1 is working on it.
3. - User 1 commits the project.
4. - User 2 tries to commit to the project and is again rejected.
5. - User 2 does Project Update and then commits your changes successfully.

Regards
JR

Comment: You want to controll it as root, or give the option that users can handle it individually?

Comment: I want to control it as a root, i know it is possible but i can't figure out.

Comment: "I Need to introduce a rule that only one person can commit..." - 1. you **don't need** this rule 2. You can have **nothing** more than manual Lock|Unlock

Answer (score 1):

In tortoise svn you have the posibillty of let the user lock a project, so its almost the behavior you want.
The only difference, a user is able to say "I know what I'm doing, and i want to acces anyway"
but excepting this, locking an repo, gives you that behavior ;)

E: in tortoisesvn 1.8 simply rightclick the project tortoisesvn->Get Lock/Release Lock

Comment: I don´t want to Lock the project, i just want a automatically recourse. Thanks for the info but i need is a pre-commit and post-commit rules.

Comment: So what is the difference? As i asked you allready before, do you want to force the user to play after this rules? Or is it what you'r talking about slightly different? the explain it plz more specific because your example would be solved by a lock/unlock

Comment: I want to force the user to dont commit will the project is open by another user. I dont want users to lock and unlock projects, i want a another way to do this whitout users interact with Tortoise or other svn application

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

- Use [Path based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).
- Use a pre-commit hook like [this one](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook)

The Path based authorization is built into Subversion and can control, read (checkout only), read-write (commit), or no-access (no checkout). The pre-commit hook can't control read authorization, but is more flexible in setting commit (read-write) authorization.

Comment: With Path Based Authetication is possible to do that?
I'm not sure...
In Path Based Authetication you can only deny or allow respositories access to the users.

Comment: @JorgeRocha See [Path based authentication](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) in the Subversion on line manual

Comment: Ok you can allow or deny file access to users, but this don't resolve my problem. I want to control the svn user commits.

Comment: @JorgeRocha use pre-commit hook to control user commits.

Comment: @JorgeRocha The path based authorization allows you to do this. The various permissions are: `w` allows commits. `r` allow checkout, but not commit, and _null_ which completely removes access. However, you can use my [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) if you prefer.

Comment: I have already this premissions on my folders, but what i need is to control the users commit that have "Write" premissions on the folder.

Comment: Then use my pre-commit hook. You can control commit permissions down to the file level. You can use globs or regular expressions to specify files. (User can edit *.java files, but not the build.xml in any project). It's simple to use and setup.